# Shape mismatch when assigning array to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty dataframe declared with 3 columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
```

and I have a Nx2 array:

```
data = np.ones((100,2))
```

I want to put my data array in two of the columns of the dataframe (colB and colC) so I tried something like:

```
df[["colB","colC"]] = data
```

But I get a shape mismatch error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (100,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (2,0)
```

I can do it column by column:

```
df["colB"] = data[:,0]
df["colC"] = data[:,1]
```

Is there a direct way of assigning an array to a dataframe?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think is possible use `DataFrame` constructor before assign:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])
df[["colB","colC"]] = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Or if want add empty columns:

```
data = np.ones((100,2))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["colB","colC"]).reindex(columns=['colA', 'colB', 'colC'])

print (df1.head())
   colA  colB  colC
0   NaN   1.0   1.0
1   NaN   1.0   1.0
2   NaN   1.0   1.0
3   NaN   1.0   1.0
4   NaN   1.0   1.0
```

Comment: The last option is the one I like the most. Thanks

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki - Agree, so added to first one ;)